# Overlapping of similar partitions!

Tags: partitioning

I have a problem with my table entries. I have two overlapped partitions. Consequently, a problem of rescue system is occurred.

[image]

---

The result of the command line is:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print

Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1 (scsi)

Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168s

Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B

Partition Table: msdos

Disk Flags: 

Number  Start       End          Size         Type      File system  Flags

 1      2048s       1126399s     1124352s     primary   ntfs

 2      1126400s    307202047s   306075648s   primary   ntfs

 3      307202048s  614402047s   307200000s   primary   nts

 4      614404094s  1953523711s  1339119618s  extended

 5      614404096s  1953523711s  1339119616s  logical
```

Comment: Where are you seeing overlapped partitions? Since you have a MBR partition table, you have a max of 4 partitions, in reality, that means 3 primary partitions and 1 extended partition, and the extended partition contains one or more logical partitions. Why don't you tell us more about the symptoms of your problem, and let us decide the best way to help you.

Comment: In reality, I'll bet that you have recently done a Windows update, and after that, you encountered problems, and Ubuntu wouldn't boot any more, correct? Your /dev/sda5 has been modified, but may be recoverable using `testdisk`.

Comment: Move boot flag back to sda1 and then Windows will boot if you have Windows boot loader in MBR.

Comment: Grub does not use boot flag. Windows has to have boot flag on primary NTFS partition with boot files or UEFI requires boot flag on ESP - efi system partition. Boot flag should never be on an extended partition anyway.

Comment: The overlapping is between sda4 and sda5

Comment: sda4 and sda5 have the same start and end points

Comment: @zora Look closer, and you'll see that the start points are different. That's how extended partitions, and logical partitions, work. Don't let that sidetrack you.

Comment: sudo sfdisk -l displays two messages 1-Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary. and 2-Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Comment: @zora Not a major problem. Continue on with my answer. Using your older Ubuntu Live USB, just skip the `sudo apt-get update` command, and see if the next command works.

Comment: @zora You'll need to use a newer Ubuntu Live USB than 19.04.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

Backup partition table before any changes, so you can get back to current if changes not correct, change example with sda to your drive if not sda.

```
sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > PT_sda.txt
```

So you know sectors:

```
sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print
```

If you post above in question, we can give more detail.

Fix overlapping partition error srs5694 Post #34

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1667614

http://www.rodsbooks.com/missing-parts/index.html

Comment: Look closer and you'll see that /dev/sda5, probably where their Ubuntu **used** to be, is gone... and probably due to a Windows update that likes to bloto Linux partitions on MBR disks.

Comment: Ok, I will try with a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows 10 Anniversary Update**, and the more recent **Windows 10 Creators Update**, have a really bad habit of wiping out Linux partitions on **MBR disks**. Microsoft has known about this bug for quite some time, but has chosen not to fix it. Sounds like you're a victim.

Recovery is possible, but it can be tricky.

Boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Open `Software & Updates` and make sure that all of your software repositories (except proposed) are enabled.

In `terminal`...

`sudo apt-get update`           # update the software database

`sudo apt-get install testdisk` # install testdisk

`man testdisk`                  # read the manual

`sudo testdisk`                 # start testdisk

You can also get specific instructions here: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Help for photorec here: https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step

**Note**: after recovery, strongly consider changing your MBR formatted disk to GPT format, so future MS updates won't wipe it again.

Comment: sudo apt-get update doesn't work!

Comment: One of the  displayed errors: Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]

Comment: @zora Are you booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: Yes, with Ubuntu Live USB (19.04).

Comment: @zora Ah! That's too old. Please make yourself one using 20.04.1, and that'll work for you. You can try the rest of my instructions with the old Live USB, and see if it works... ie: skip the `sudo apt-get update` part.

Comment: Here is the result of "sudo apt-get install testdisk" Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package testdisk

Comment: @zora OK, we tried. You'll have to build yourself a newer Ubuntu Live USB.

Comment: @zora Status please...

Comment: The result of testdisk:

Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63

Current partition structure:

 Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

1 P HPFS - NTFS 0 32 33 70 29 23 1124352 [R erv au syst e]

2 P HPFS - NTFS 70 29 24 19122 112 62 306075648

3 P HPFS - NTFS 19122 112 63 38244 193 29 307200000 [DATA]

4 E extended 38244 225 60 121601 57 56 1339119618

No partition is bootable

No ext2, JFS, Reiser, cramfs or XFS marker

5 L Linux 38244 225 62 121601 57 56 1339119616

5 L Linux 38244 225 62 121601 57 56 1339119616

Comment: @zora `Testdisk` looks like it has properly found your Ubuntu partition. Follow the step-by-step instructions at the link that I gave in my answer. I really can't help remote control at this point.